# AsyncHttpClient send multipart/form-data

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I use a AsyncHttpClient to send a request.
I have to send to server multipart/form-data it should be like :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/SC_TerminalAssist/proxy/photos/note HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: SCToken b970d85e-278b1163-1592-4e9c-9255-459022a585e7
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="----=_Part_4_1087532223.1512997169142"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 869
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
------=_Part_4_1087532223.1512997169142
Content-Type: application/json; name=login_param.json
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="login_param.json"
{
   "company": "elte gps",
   "user": "franek",
   "secure_password": "C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B",
   "secure_device_id": "C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B"
}
------=_Part_4_1087532223.1512997169142
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=Cp1250; name=login_param.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photos"; filename="login_param.xml"
<login_param>
<company>elte gps</company>
<user>franek</user>
<secure_password>C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B</secure_password>
<secure_device_id>C4CA4238A0B923820DCC509A6F75849B</secure_device_id>
</login_param>
------=_Part_4_1087532223.1512997169142--
```

I did this but it doesn't work as expected. I want to send a photo and a json to the server. I use the same parameters from API Request in the android client the request doesn't work correctly.

```
private void uploadFileExecute(File file, String token) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    SharedPreferences sp ;
    sp = getSharedPreferences("pfref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String pass = sp.getString("pass", "");
    String firm = sp.getString("firm", "");
    String login = sp.getString("login", "");

    try {
        jsonObject.put("company", firm);
        jsonObject.put("user", login);
        jsonObject.put("secure_password", HashUtil.md5(pass));
        jsonObject.put("secure_device_id", HashUtil.md5(DeviceUtil.getDeviceId(PhotoActivity.this)));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    BasicHeader[] headers = new BasicHeader[]{new BasicHeader("Authorization", "SCToken " + token)};
    try {
        params.put("photos", file);
        params.put("filename",jsonObject);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

    client.post(PhotoActivity.this, RestClient.getAbsoluteUrl("photos/note"), headers, params, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Log.d("sokces", "uploadFile response: " + statusCode);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.d("sokces nie", "uploadFile ERROR! " + statusCode);
        }
    });
}
```

When run the code, I  receive a status code 415, I am not sure what went wrong.

Comment: `status code 415`. What does that mean?

Comment: `I have to send to server multipart/form-data it should be like `. Are you shure? That is sending two files.  filename="login_param.json" and filename="login_param.xml". For both there is a white line missing. You are not sending files or pretending as if, it looks.

Comment: `params.put("photos", file);` Does that compile?

Comment: `params.put("filename",jsonObject);` ????

Comment: Use an Apache Tcpmon and start forwarding request from port 91 to port 80, where your native service is hosted. Compare the difference between the Request.Your problem will be solved.  Apache Tcpmon -> https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/